# Laravel export to my domain server?

Tags: laravel

I feel really left in the dark when it comes to trying to uploading my laravel website. I need a virtual host to access the public folder on my localhost. How can this be done on my site? I am currently getting this:

www.smks.co.uk

and if i access public get a strange error

www.smks.co.uk/public

Comment: What verison are PHP are you running? You should be able to place the folders (except public) above your web root (which is the idea), and then specify the new folder as your public folder in the config files. So for example, you may have "httpdocs" as your web folder, rename public to httpdocs in your config files, move all contents from public into httpdocs, rest of files go above httpdocs.

Comment: 5.3 I am with GoDaddy and I cannot move the folders any higher than the html folder that needs the default file

Comment: You'll need to use .htaccess then to rewrite requests into the public folder (or get a decent host).

Answer (score 0):

If you use shared hosting, probably your hosting provider doesn't let to build a virtual host. You need to change directories and configuration a little bit. I have uploaded several websites to shared hosting by using [this method](http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=4977).

Comment: Surely there is a simple method. Should not be this problematic

Comment: Sure. There is another way to handle. You can upload your files to root and use your public_html (or httpdocs) as your public directory. But some hosting provider doesn't let even reaching to root directory by using php. So it doesn't work all the time.